# arguments in generate series cannot be blank error

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

i am trying to apply levenshtein distance to 2 columns, tables and getting error in generate series cannot be blank.Here is my code.

```
Measure = 
VAR SlicerText =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Slicer Table'[TestColumn] )
VAR TableText =
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'Table'[TestColumn] )
VAR length =
    MAX ( LEN ( SlicerText ), LEN ( TableText ) )
VAR TestTable =
    ADDCOLUMNS (
        GENERATESERIES ( 1, length, 1 ),
        "InSlicer", MID ( SlicerText, [Value], 1 ),
        "InTable", MID ( TableText, [Value], 1 )
    )
RETURN
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( TestTable, [InSlicer] = [InTable] ) )
        / COUNTROWS ( TestTable )
```

Comment: any help appreciated!

Comment: Fuzzy Lookup or any similar algo ??

Answer (score 2):

With a little effort you could have figured this out yourself:

1. The error message tells you that one of the parameters of GENERATESERIES() is blank. This can ONLY be the *length* variable.
2. *length* is blank when both variables SlicerText and TableText are blank.
3. both variables refer to the SELECTEDVALUE() function, which returns blank if none or more than one rows are selected and you didn't provide an *alternateResult*, see the official documentation here: [SELECTEDVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/selectedvalue-function)

Bottom line: Make shure you have exactly one row selectd in 'Slicer Table' and 'Table'.

This is as much help as you can get, since you didn't share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as recommended by StackOverflow.

Comment: thank you , the above code only compares a single character, is there any to compare whole text line?

Comment: hi peter i have updated my question, can you please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73725488/similarity-of-two-text-in-power-bi-fuzzy-lookup-or-cosine-similarity-based-on